# I would like to lookup and display an adjacent cell's value based on the value of 2 cells behind it (2 arguments)

Tags: arguments, vlookup

I HAVE THIS FORMULA =VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$B$5517,2,FALSE)
that looks up adjacent cell's value based on E2,
I WOULD LIKE TO LOOKUP BASED ON TWO ADJACENT VALUES SUCH AS
E2&F2

=VLOOKUP(E2&F2,$A$2:$B$5517,2,FALSE)
RETURNS #N/A